# ASP.NET MVC 4 passing values between lists

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have a following problem: I have form, which has some dropdowns, textareas etc. and also I have two tables:
- SelectedItems
- AvailableItems
This two tables are a result of rendering two lists in my Model. What I need to do is when user press add button in a defined item row then I move item from AvailableItems to SelectedItems. My idea was to operate on lists so add to one, remove from another. I have no idea how to update lists of objects which can be found in model

```
   public class Model
   {
      public List<Item> SelectedItems {get; set;}
      public List<Item> AvailableItems {get; set;}
      //other properties
   }
```

My Partial View is:

```
<table>
<thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th>ID</th>
                            <th>Name</th>
                            <th>Description</th>
                            <th></th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>

                    @if (Model.SelectedItems != null)
                    {
                        foreach (var item in Model.SelectedItems)
                        {
                        <tr>
                            <td>
                                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.ID)
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Name)
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Description)
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                @Html.ActionLink("Add", "RemoveItem", new { ItemID = item.ID}, new { @class = "btn btn-primary" })
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        }
                    }

</table>

<table>
<thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th>ID</th>
                            <th>Name</th>
                            <th>Description</th>
                            <th></th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>

                    @if (Model.AvailableItems != null)
                    {
                        foreach (var item in Model.AvailableItems)
                        {
                        <tr>
                            <td>
                                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.ID)
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Name)
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Description)
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                @Html.ActionLink("Add", "AddItem", new { ItemID = item.ID}, new { @class = "btn btn-primary" })
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        }
                    }

</table>
```

Problem is that I can't reload whole page. I need to make inserts do db basing on that form so is there any possibility to update model and then start inserts?
Thank you for your help.

Comment: You don't give enough information here.  Can we assume that Model is actually just the view model?  Or are you updating a data model as well?  Is it defined exactly the same way?  how do you do these updates?

Comment: Nope - I don't use ViewModel - I have just one model which contains all properties. I assumed that there is no reason to create ViewModel because I have to send 99% properties to db. I don't modify data model. I just wanted to collect data and then basing on that data create EF objects and then submit them to DB. Tbh by ViewModel I understand model which contains only properties which should be displayed by View so it shouldn't be any difference between my approach and with ViewModel usage.

Comment: You need to use AJAX. Look up jquery/ajax. All you have to do is create an ajax post/get function which is called when you click your actionlink. this function posts/gets to an MVC Action which can return a JSON string of your updated lists. then your ajax function on success reloads the lists only (not the page).

Comment: Thx for idea. But still will I be able to submit that updated list with rest of model and save it to db?